# Puerta XOR - Python

Tags: python, bucle-for, while, random

Estoy tratando de programar un ejemplo simple de como resolver un problema tipo XOR, la idea a grandes rasgos es: Generar pesos aleatorios (P) para que la salida (Salida) sea igual a la salida esperada (Y).

El siguiente código me funciona perfectamente:

```
import random 
    E1 = [-1,0,0]
    E2 = [-1,0,1]
    E3 = [-1,1,0]
    E4 = [-1,1,1]
    Entrada = [E1,E2,E3,E4]
    Y = [0,1,1,1]
    Salida = []


for E in Entrada: 
        P =  np.random.choice(np.arange(0, 1.5, 0.5), size=3).tolist()
        S = E[0]*P[0]+E[1]*P[1]+E[2]*P[2]
        if S >= 0:
            F = 1
        else:
            F = 0
        Salida.append(F)
print(P)
print(Y)
print(Salida)
Y == Salida
```

El problema es cuando trato de usar un bucle while para que repita el for hasta que Y = Salida, pero no parece llegar a converger y se queda ejecutando el for infinitamente. Algo que no debería puesto que ejecutando el código arriba mencionado tres o cuatro veces ya se cumple la condición "Y==Salida" output: True

¿Alguien puede decirme que hay de erróneo al introducir aquí el bucle while?

```
import random 
E1 = [-1,0,0]
E2 = [-1,0,1]
E3 = [-1,1,0]
E4 = [-1,1,1]
Entrada = [E1,E2,E3,E4]
Y = [0,1,1,1]
Salida = []

while Y != Salida: 
    for E in Entrada: 
        P =  np.random.choice(np.arange(0, 1.5, 0.5), size=3).tolist()
        S = E[0]*P[0]+E[1]*P[1]+E[2]*P[2]
        if S >= 0:
            F = 1
        else:
            F = 0
        Salida.append(F)
print(P)
print(Y)
print(Salida)
Y == Salida
```

Gracias y un saludo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedo comentar, pero tu bucle While se ejecutara de manera infinita, debido a que tu salida ira incrementando a medida que se ejecute este ciclo, es decir:

1° vuelta:

Salida = [1, 1, 1, 1]

2° vuelta:

Salida = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]

Para tal caso debes limpiar tu salida por cada vuelta que da el while.

Comment: Oh entiendo, solo debo declarar la lista "Salida = []" vacía dentro del bucle. Ya lo he corregido y me funciona perfectamente. Gracias!

Comment: De nada, me alegro haberte ayudado.